# Bootstrap Caret collapsing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working on this Bootstrap reskinning project, and I ran into this really odd bug with the buttons.

The caret in the dropdown seem to be collapsing when used with the `btn-lg` class (as shown in the two images below). I've did a comparison on the compiled css on the `btn`, the `dropdown-toggle` and `caret`, and nothing significant (other than margin, padding, colors etc) seem to be different.

Any help would be much appreciated! thanks!

[image: Collapsed caret]

[image: Original Bootstrap caret]

Comment: please add your code to the question, or better create an additional bootply, so that we can recreate your problem (http://www.bootply.com/uwXE9EQ0hQ)

Comment: So what exactly is your question?